# Server's error respons hits the success callback on frontend

Tags: javascript, rest, axios

I have a code that does a *GET* request:

```
axios.get('/getsome').then((data) => onSuccess(data), (error) => onError(error));
```

The server returns `409` (*CONFLICT*) status. I expect `onError` to be called, but instead `onSuccess` is always called.

How is that possible? I saw with my own eyes in chrome dev tools that the status of response is 409.

---

UPD: I created a mock server with nodejs' express:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()


app.get('/getsome', (req, res) => {
  res.status(409);
  res.send(undefined);
})
```

**And it hits `onError` callback**! Now I completely do not understand: 2 different servers return same error code, but different callbacks fired.

Comment: well now that you have 2 requests - one that fails and one that succeeds, try to look at the exact response (in dev tools, or maybe with Postman) and look whats different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was following: in other place we use http interceptor to connect axios with `nprogress` library. After that connection was removed the error handling returned to normal.

So a general tip: in such cases **check http interceptors** and disconnect/fix them.

Answer (score 0):

try replace the position `res` to `req`, like this: `app.get('/getsome', (req, res) => {`

Comment: That was a typo, thank you. But I guess that's not the case

Comment: strange. You sure that your server response error 409? Try  axios then().catch()

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following code to make the get request it gives the correct error code and jumps inside the catch block. This is my standard way of handling errors in axios and it should fix your issue. Please give it a try.

```js
axios.get('/getsome')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("error")
  });
```